# Latch data when differs from zeros

Tags: vhdl, fpga

Is there any way to latch data in combinational circuit when it differs from zero and keep it latched as long as clear signal is '0'. So I have no clock signal, no latch trigger. I tried this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity tester is
    Port ( inData       : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
           inClear      : in  std_logic;
           outStatus        : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)         
           );
end tester;

architecture Behavioral of tester is

signal Data :  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal NotZero :  std_logic;


begin

with inData select
NotZero <=  '0' when "0000",
            '1' when others;

Data <= inData when (NotZero = '1') else Data;
outStatus <= Data;

end Behavioral;
```

But when `inData` goes back to zeros `outStatus` does the same.

Comment: In a synthesized application there may be no guarantee of the propagation times of elements of inData which means NotZero may not be glitch free. You shouldn't produce latch enables combinationally.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: This is Static Hazard 101 - look it up. If you can't fix the VHDL to *correctly* cover the hazard, ask again and I'll post the code. It is very unlikely that the synth will correctly cover the hazard if you don't *explicitly* code the gates. You should also have posted your testbench, so that we know why you think it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a [delta race](https://vhdlwhiz.com/delta-cycles-explained/) condition where `NotZero` and `Data` are both dependent on `inData`, but `Data` is also dependent on `NotZero = '1'`. `NotZero` changes to `'0'` in the current delta cycle, but the `Data` expression has not seen this update. `Data` is responding to the previous delta iteration where `inData` changed to `"0000"` and `NotZero` was still `'1'`.

Your synthesis tool is likely smart enough to remove the intermediate `NotZero` signal, and then you would not see the issue in real-life.

Why not compare directly to the value of `inData`?:

```
Data <= (others=>'0') when inClear='1' else
        inData when (inData/="0000") else                 
        Data;
outStatus <= Data;
```

**Note:** I've made an assumption as to what your `inClear` is doing. You can change that to do whatever you want.